# ggplot: stat_summary for mean with facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Within ggplot2, I am using the `stat_summary()` function to calculate and plot the mean and standard deviation of a dataset.  I am simultaneously using `facet_wrap()` to break the dataset into two plots.
I was pleasantly surprised that adding `facet_wrap()` to my ggplot caused `stat_summary()` to correctly be applied to each subset of the data independently.

```
df>
| ID        | Group | Strain | Condition | DoublingTime    |
|-----------|-------|--------|-----------|-----------------|
| A_3g_Rep1 | A_3g  | A      | 3g        |     122.4135    |
| A_3g_Rep2 | A_3g  | A      | 3g        |     124.5801    |
| A_3g_Rep3 | A_3g  | A      | 3g        |     124.9419    |
| A_6g_Rep1 | A_6g  | A      | 6g        |     120.5004    |
| A_6g_Rep2 | A_6g  | A      | 6g        |     124.1666    |
| A_6g_Rep3 | A_6g  | A      | 6g        |     124.6453    |
| B_3g_Rep1 | B_3g  | B      | 3g        |     132.568     |
| B_3g_Rep2 | B_3g  | B      | 3g        |     137.5242    |
| B_3g_Rep3 | B_3g  | B      | 3g        |     135.5238    |
| B_6g_Rep1 | B_6g  | B      | 6g        |     137.1333    |
| B_6g_Rep2 | B_6g  | B      | 6g        |     142.733     |
| B_6g_Rep3 | B_6g  | B      | 6g        |     140.0722    |
```

First, I was using the following which correctly calculates mean and standard deviation values.  However, it includes groups on the x-axis aren't present in the facet.

```
DT_plotA <- ggplot(df, aes(Group, DoublingTime)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1),
               geom="errorbar", width=0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", size=3) +
  facet_wrap(nrow = 1, .~Strain)
```

[image: DT_plotA]


I was pleasantly surprised that adjusting my aes() x-value to Condition while including facet_wrap() caused stat_summary() to correctly calculate mean and standard deviation for each Group correctly.

```
DT_plotB <- ggplot(df, aes(Condition, DoublingTime)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1),
               geom="errorbar", width=0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", size=3) +
  facet_wrap(nrow = 1, .~Strain)
```

[image: DT_plotB]


However, if facet_wrap is removed from the plot, stat_summary calculates mean and standard deviation based on Condition: data from independent Strains is averaged.  I worry that this caveat will be forgotten and lead to incorrect calculation of mean/sd when facet is removed.

```
DT_plotC <- ggplot(df, aes(Condition, DoublingTime)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1),
               geom="errorbar", width=0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", size=3)
```

[image: DT_plotC]


**Question**
Is there a way to generate a plot that looks like DT_plotB but instead includes aes(Group, DoublingTime) as in shown in the code for DT_plotA?

Comment: Maybe `facet_wrap(nrow = 1, .~Strain, scales = "free_x")` to include only the groups that are present in the facet?

Comment: That works!  Is there a way to replace the x-axis labels with the values from another column?  For instance if I wanted each Condition to be the text instead of Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we could do it with some preprocessing of the data -> calculating the mean and sd:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(Strain, Condition) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(DoublingTime),
         sd = sd(DoublingTime)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Condition, y=mean)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd, ymax = mean+sd), width=.2)+
  facet_wrap(.~Strain)
```

[image]